# How can override a add_filter of a plugin?

Tags: filters, plugin-wpml

How can I override add_filter of a plugin?

**like**

```
add_filter( 'wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'cart_switching_currency', 10, 4 );
```

I want to use my custom function instead "cart_switching_currency" function.

Answer (score 3):

Filters come with a priority parameter, the default is 10, so to override a function you need to increase the priority:

```
add_filter( 'wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'cart_switching_currency', 99, 4 );
```

> add_filter( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority =
>   10, int $accepted_args = 1 )

More info in the [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

Update:

If removing a filter is not working you may try this approach:

```
function remove_cart_switching_currency_filter(){
    remove_filter('wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'cart_switching_currency', 10, 4);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_cart_switching_currency_filter' );
```

**Important is that the priorities must match.**

More info about [after_setup_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme)

Comment: You need to remove the original filter first. If not, it will still affect the data, which you might not want to.

Comment: I added this code in child theme.. **remove_filter( 'wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'cart_switching_currency', 10 ); add_filter( 'wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'ipe_cart_switching_currency', 99, 4 );** but it is till calling plugin function.

Comment: You are correct @JackJohansson. Reading the override I think just that. Thinking if I delete my answer or not.

Comment: @Suman maybe because the filter called after the remove filter of your child theme. You can try the remove in the init of your theme

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`remove_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/) to remove a filter, and then add your own filter to that hook. For example:

```
remove_filter( 'wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'cart_switching_currency', 10 );

add_filter( 'wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'my_function', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: I already tried this. It is not working..

Comment: You might be doing this too early or late. Also, the priority matters here.

Comment: I added this code in child theme.. **remove_filter( 'wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'cart_switching_currency', 10 );
 add_filter( 'wcml_switch_currency_exception', 'ipe_cart_switching_currency', 99, 4 );**